# using POST in ajax in vanilla js

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

I am trying to send the post request to my PHP file but it is saying undefined index.

my js code -

```
document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener('click', xh );

function xh(){
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //xhr.open('GET', 'req.php?msg=hello bro', true);
    xhr.open('POST', 'req.php');
    xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-type', 'application/w-xxx-form-urlencoded');
    
    xhr.onprogress = function () {
       // document.getElementById("loading").classList.remove("dis");
    }
    xhr.onload = function () {          
        console.log(this.responseText);
    }
    
        xhr.send("msg=hello");        
    }
```

my PHP code -

```
 <?php
        if(isset($_POST['msg'])){
            echo "set";
        }
        else{
            echo "not set";
        }
    ?>
```

I also tried the server request method but it didn't work

it is showing not set, and if I try to echo the `$_POST['msg'];` it says undefined index 'msg'

Comment: make life easier on yourself and start using the `fetch` api - it is a much cleaner api and ties in nicely with Promises

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-type', 'application/w-xxx-form-urlencoded');
```

you want to set the request header

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

Read more about [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). The present approach it to use [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) though.

```
fetch("req.php", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
  body: "msg=hello"
}).then(response => response.text())
  .then(console.log)
```